# Group sorted list in Jinja

Tags: group-by, jinja2

It seems that you cannot group sorted lists in jinja without loosing the sort order.

Here an example template:

```
{% set l = [{'c': 3, 'result': 1.0},
            {'c': 3, 'result': 2.0},
            {'c': 9, 'result': 3.0},
            {'c': 1, 'result': 4.0}] %}
{% for d in l|groupby('c') %}
    {{d}}
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, this templates outputs:

```
(1, [{'c': 1, 'result': 4.0}])
(3, [{'c': 3, 'result': 1.0}, {'c': 3, 'result': 2.0}])
(9, [{'c': 9, 'result': 3.0}])
```

But what I was expecting is:

```
(3, [{'c': 3, 'result': 1.0}, {'c': 3, 'result': 2.0}])
(9, [{'c': 9, 'result': 3.0}])
(1, [{'c': 1, 'result': 4.0}])
```

I have absolutely to keep the items in the pre-sorted order.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: The results are passed through `sorted`: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/8261473c68993cbbf3460351a1a75be2a04ab245/jinja2/filters.py#L663-L702

Answer (score 2):

hopefully this answer solves your problem

```
{% for d in l|groupby('c')|reverse %}
   {{d}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated to the latest jinja version:

```
import jinja2

from jinja2 import environmentfilter
from itertools import groupby
from jinja2.filters import make_attrgetter, _GroupTuple

@environmentfilter
def do_sorted_groupby(environment, value, attribute):
    expr = make_attrgetter(environment, attribute)
    return [_GroupTuple(key, list(values)) for key, values
            in groupby(value, expr)]

env = jinja2.Environment()
env.filters['sorted_groupby'] = do_sorted_groupby

ret = env.from_string('''
{% set l = [{'c': 3, 'result': 1.0},
            {'c': 3, 'result': 2.0},
            {'c': 9, 'result': 3.0},
            {'c': 1, 'result': 4.0}] %}
{% for d in l|sorted_groupby('c') %}
    {{d}}
{% endfor %}
''').render()

print(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Blender pointed out in his comment, jinja uses `sorted` to sort the passed list according to the received key.

In case you want to keep the sort-order, I fear the only solution is to write your own jinja-filter.

Here the filter I implemented to achieve this:

```
from jinja2 import environmentfilter
from itertools import groupby
from jinja2.filters import make_attrgetter, _GroupTuple
@environmentfilter
def do_groupby(environment, value, attribute):
    expr = make_attrgetter(environment, attribute)
    return map(_GroupTuple, groupby(value, expr))
```

*Caution*: This filter is only working if the received list is **grouped** correctly (The group-indicator must be in sequence). This list, for example  will not group correctly:

```
[{'c': 3, 'result': 1.0},
 {'c': 9, 'result': 2.0},
 {'c': 3, 'result': 3.0},
 {'c': 1, 'result': 4.0}]
```